# How to repeat a value in a column based on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'b': [None, 'w', None, 'z']
})
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 1 | 'w' |
| 2 | None |
| 2 | 'z' |

And I want to repeat the values that are not `None` in column 'b', but based on the value in column 'a'.

At the end I would have this dataframe:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'w' |
| 1 | 'w' |
| 2 | 'z' |
| 2 | 'z' |

Comment: what if there was a 3rd row 1/None  after 1/w? And what if you had more that 1 values (e.g. w and x) in group 1? how would you like to fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear on how you would like to generalize, but you could `bfill`/`ffill` per group:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```

output:

```
   a  b
0  1  w
1  1  w
2  2  z
3  2  z
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit tricky but it works. Basically what happen is that for each subsample of 'a' we are going to fill na values with the column 'b'. I'm assuming that for each element of 'a' there exist only one value of 'b' and no more

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1, 1, 2, 2],
        'b': [None, 'w', None, 'z']})

df

        a   b
    0   1   None
    1   1   w
    2   2   None
    3   2   z
    
for i in df['a'].unique():
    df[df['a']==i] = df[df['a']==i].fillna(df[df['a']==i].dropna()['b'].iloc[0])
        
    
df
        a   b
    0   1   w
    1   1   w
    2   2   z
    3   2   z
```